# Range of the distribution of $(1-X)$ when $X$ follows Beta distribution as $X\sim beta(p,q)$

Tags: statistics, limits, probability-distributions

if $X$ follows beta distribution with parameter $p$ and $q$  where $p>0\quad ,  q>0$

then $1-X$ follows beta distribution with parameters $q$ and $p$,

that is if $X\sim beta(p,q)$ then $(1-X)\sim beta(q,p)$

i have come up with the result but the range of the distribution of $1-X$ is coming 1 to 0,that is,

$1<(1-x)<0$

i computed the limit thus:

if $x=0$ ,then , $(1-x)=(1-0)=1$

and if $x=1$ ,then , $(1-x)=(1-1)=0$

But the range should be $0<(1-x)<1$  otherwise i can't conclude  with the result that

if $X\sim beta(p,q)$ then $(1-X)\sim beta(q,p)$
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decomposing the double inequality:

- $x\lt1\iff 1-x\gt0$
- $x\gt0\iff 1-x\lt1$
- $0\lt x\lt1\iff$ $___$ $\lt1-x\lt$ $___$

Or: plot the graph of the function $u:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, $x\mapsto u(x)=1-x$.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much.